# Check IP address used for a request Python/Scrapy + ProxyMesh

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, request, scrapy

I started to use ProxyMesh with Scrapy. ProxyMesh is supposed to provide a pool of IP addresses on one port. The sample code code below is being repeated in a loop, middleware is enabled and overall this works fine. Can I track (and if so - how?) which IP address is being used for each specific request?

```
request = scrapy.Request(producturl, self.parse_product_info)
request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://uk.proxymesh.com:xxx'
yield request
```

I found similar posts on SOF, but not addressing this specific question.

Comment: maybe proxymesh returns that information inside the headers, you could try to print that on the response: `print response.headers`. btw, [crawlera](http://crawlera.com/) does indeed return the used proxy on the response headers.

Comment: This is a good hint. There is a response header: X-Proxymesh-Ip. I was able to parse it as response.headers.get('X-Proxymesh-Ip'). I wanter if the fact that ProxyMesh is used is also visible to the site's admin, and is it possible to hide this?

Comment: of course the site will know which proxy (or IP) is used for crawling their site, but that `X-Proxymesh-Ip` is only returned to you. At least that is how [crawlera](http://crawlera.com) works.

Comment: ok, thank you. I did not find for sure that this is not visible at ProxyMesh, but I'll try without worrying about this too much..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like specified in the comments, the information comes on the response headers, just check it:

```
def parse_response(self, response):
    print response.headers
```

You should see the `X-Proxymesh-Ip` header with the assigned proxy.

Another alternative could be to use [crawlera](http://crawlera.com) which offers even more features (like headers, sessions and cookie handling) and better documentation.